# get zoomed image bitmap height and width in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to get ImageView's Height and Width after Zoom in Zoom out.

I am using the following code:

```
mRectSrc.left = (int)(panX * bitmapWidth - viewWidth / (zoomX * 2));
            mRectSrc.top = (int)(panY * bitmapHeight - viewHeight / (zoomY * 2));
            mRectSrc.right = (int)(mRectSrc.left + viewWidth / zoomX);
            mRectSrc.bottom = (int)(mRectSrc.top + viewHeight / zoomY);
            mRectDst.left = getLeft();
            mRectDst.top = getTop();
            mRectDst.right = getRight();
            mRectDst.bottom = getBottom();

            // Adjust source rectangle so that it fits within the source image.
            if (mRectSrc.left < 0) {
                mRectDst.left += -mRectSrc.left * zoomX;
                mRectSrc.left = 0;
            }
            if (mRectSrc.right > bitmapWidth) {
                mRectDst.right -= (mRectSrc.right - bitmapWidth) * zoomX;
                mRectSrc.right = bitmapWidth;
            }
            if (mRectSrc.top < 0) {
                mRectDst.top += -mRectSrc.top * zoomY;
                mRectSrc.top = 0;
            }
            if (mRectSrc.bottom > bitmapHeight) {
                mRectDst.bottom -= (mRectSrc.bottom - bitmapHeight) * zoomY;
                mRectSrc.bottom = bitmapHeight;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mRectSrc, mRectDst, mPaint);
```

So using This code i am getting zoom effect on image. How Can i Get Bitmap Height and width after zoom in and zoom out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried looking for some inbuilt function for getting the size of the bitmap attached with the image view but couldn't find any. So, I made a workaround. Just store the initial height and width of the bitmap in some variable and then update these variable values with the scale factor.
This is how you can get the bitmap attached with the image(will always return the initial size):

```
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
    float w = bmp.getWidth();
    float h = bmp.getHeight();
```

Method to update the values:

```
public void updateSize(float scaleFactor)
{
     w *= scaleFactor;
     h *= scaleFactor;
}
```

You can call this method from where you are adding zoom to the image.